# Adobe Acrobat Plugin - create sub menu item in context menu

Tags: c++, c, acrobat, acrobat-sdk

I add an menu Item to "select" context menu, and I wont to add sub menu item to my menu item, is it possible? and if yes please tell me how.

```cpp
ASText t = ASTextNew();
ASTextSetEncoded(t, "menu item text", (ASHostEncoding)PDGetHostEncoding());
AVMenuItem menuItem = AVMenuItemNewWithASText(t, btnAddFromCurrent, NULL, true, NO_SHORTCUT, 0, NULL, gExtensionID);
AVMenuAddMenuItem(menu, menuItem, APPEND_MENUITEM);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line:

`AVMenuItem menuItem = AVMenuItemNewWithASText(t, btnAddFromCurrent, NULL, true, NO_SHORTCUT, 0, NULL, gExtensionID);`

pass an `AVMenu` instance instead of `NULL`